# latency in netty due to passing requests from boss thread to worker thread?

Tags: java, performance, tcp, netty, tcplistener

I have some questions about Netty (Server Side), TCP/IP applications;

I am wondering if there can be latency because of netty (due to missing configuration etc.) while passing the request from boss thread to worker thread ?

I am using :

```
new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(350, 0, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Actually, I set max thread count `350` as I am not sure about the optimal number. I log simultaneous working thread count every minute and it seems that average is too low (barely exceeds `10`). So I will decrease this number as it is not required.

Is there any other parameters,important points that I should be aware of for to get best performance ?

`bootstrap.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);` -  Is there any disadvantage of setting this parameter?  Considering that delivery time is very important.

Thread Pool Executer:

```
OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor executor = new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(48, 0, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Here is my pipeline factory:

```
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(GProperties.getIntProperty("decoder.maxFrameLength", 8000 * 1024), Delimiters.nulDelimiter()));
    pipeline.addLast("stringDecoder", new StringDecoder( CharsetUtil.UTF_8 ));      
    pipeline.addLast("frameEncoder", new NullTermMessageEncoder());
    pipeline.addLast("stringEncoder", new JSONEncoder( CharsetUtil.UTF_8 ));
        pipeline.addLast("timeout", new IdleStateHandler(idleTimer, 42 , 0, 0));
    pipeline.addLast("executor", new ExecutionHandler(executor));
    pipeline.addLast("handler", new GServerHandler());
```

and the ServerBootstrap:

```
gServerBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
        gServerBootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new GServerPipelineFactory());
                gServerBootstrap.setOption("backlog", 8129);
                gServerBootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
        gServerBootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(GProperties.getIntProperty("server.port", 7679)));
```

What can you suggest for this configuration ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Netty Boss threads are only used to setup connection, worker threads are used to run NioWorker (non blocking read/write) or OioWorker (blocking read/write).

If you have an execution handler, worker thread will submit the message event to OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.

1) Increasing the Netty I/O worker thread count to more than number of processors * 2  won't     help. If you are using staged executors, Having more than one staged execution handler for non I/O tasks, may increase latency.

Note: Its better to set your own ObjectSizeEstimator implementation in  OMTPE 
        constructor, because many CPU cycles are spent on calculating used channel memory.

2) There are some other Netty parameters you can try

```
   //setting buffer size can improve I/O
   bootstrap.setOption("child.sendBufferSize", 1048576);
   bootstrap.setOption("child.receiveBufferSize", 1048576); 

   // better to have an receive buffer predictor 
   bootstrap.setOption("receiveBufferSizePredictorFactory", new AdaptiveReceiveBufferSizePredictorFactory(MIN_PACKET_SIZE, INITIAL_PACKET_SIZE, MAX_PACKET_SIZE))  

   //if the server is sending 1000 messages per sec, optimum write buffer water marks will
   //prevent unnecessary throttling, Check NioSocketChannelConfig doc   
   bootstrap.setOption("writeBufferLowWaterMark", 32 * 1024);
   bootstrap.setOption("writeBufferHighWaterMark", 64 * 1024);
```

3) It should be bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true) for server bootstrap.

There is an experimental hidden parameter:

Netty NioWorker is using SelectorUtil.select to wait for selector events, the wait time is hard coded in SelectorUtil,

```
selector.select(500);
```

setting a small value gave better performance in netty sctp transport implementation. Not sure about TCP.

Comment: do i have to do something at operating system level (server) for tcpNoDelay ? Changing configuration, setting global environment variable etc ? Server is Centos.

Comment: You can use sysctl command to tune tcp stack parameters in linux, But tcp no delay is a socket level parameter, so you have to use bootstrap.setOption

Comment: Tuning TCP stack will be very specific to your performance requirement, and there are plenty of articles out there. These are the  parameters I can see in my 2.6 Kernel https://gist.github.com/1554191

Comment: how can buffer sizes and WaterMarks effect netty performance ?

Comment: 1)setting optimum size for socket buffers reduce the number of read/write calls 2) setting the write water mark size prevent unnecessary throttling (going to read only mode)

Answer (score 1):

Q1) Everything adds latency. Netty is pretty efficient so I would be surprised if the latency is too high for 95%+ of use cases

Q2) Test you performance yourself and determine if it a problem, (either latency or throughput) before you start worrying about it.

Q3) This option may help.  It shouldn't make it worse.  Many modern OSes self tune pretty well and I don't find it makes as much difference as it used to.

Can you clarify what latency you are trying to achieve because it can make a big difference to your design?  Is it 10 ms, 1 ms, 100 us, 10 us?

Comment: Peter, i know that it will sound crazy but can it exceed 1000 ms ? About your answer to Q2 latency is very important since this application is a game server. But catching the actual problem is too hard since, it may be because of many reasons like slow internet connection of client, poor client pc etc. .

Comment: Depending on what you are doing the latency can exceed 1000 ms. However it is possible to design systems which have less than 100 micro-seconds latency in Java (for the parts in your control)

Comment: There is NO WAY that the latency of handing off a work unit from a netty IO thread to a worker thread is 1000ms, unless there are no available threads. In my experience (and I'm running several hundred servers with millions of users) it's ~ 1-2ms.

Comment: I suspect the OP needs a better understand of where his latency is coming from. I would suggest he time stamp all the stages in in the life cycle of an event, e.g. receiving, handling and responding to a request. You can ping servers on the other side of the world in 300 ms (round trip)

Answer (score 0):

> 1) I am wondering if there can be latency because of netty (due to missing configuration etc.) while passing the request from boss thread to worker thread ?

I don't think there's much if any latency here. The threads are in a pool, they just need to be given the work.

> QUESTION 2) Is there any other parameters,important points that I should be aware of for to get best performance ?

When it comes to 'best' performance, I did a bunch of testing and ended up using a number of threads that was about 16* the number of physical processors on the box. I tried thread numbers up to several thousand, but when they got really slammed, they ended up thrashing in GC.

> QUESTION 3) bootstrap.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);. Is there any disadvantage of setting this parameter ? Considering that delivery time is very important.

Definitely set this.

Comment: i ll try setting tcpNoDelay parameter. since this is a game server update will have to wait for night =) by the way why 16 ??

Comment: please correct me if I get it right -> 16 x (number of processors)

Comment: That ended up being the best tradeoff of threads, throughput and memory use.

Comment: Yes. But like I said - I tested all kinds of different things.

Comment: Kylar, is it worth looking log messages of Netty ?

Comment: For performance? Or for error tracking? Logs are always useful, but it depends on what you're trying to find out.

Comment: for performance ? forexample i want to know the time pass between my socket write call and the actuall write operations starts. As far as I know it is asynchronous.

Comment: Ahh, I see. yes, you'll have to create some custom logs for that, but it can be very helpful.

Comment: With custom logs do you mean like using ChannelFuture object to check when the write operation is done and log the time difference ?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to timestamp when the socket write is finished and when the work is finished. We generate a unique UUID for each request when we accept it then pass it along in the context so we can correlate them in our logs.

Comment: do i have to do something at operating system level (server) for tcpNoDelay ? Changing configuration, setting global environment variable etc ? Server is Centos.