# Is one port for read, one port for write a good idea for socket applications?

Tags: java, performance, tcp, netty

I am wondering if it is a good idea to have 2 separate ports one for read, one for write ? Can I expect better performance ?

**NOTE:** Server is Centos, Client is flash, message format in communication is JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to have it in TCP with a single port, also depending if you are using NIO or not,

Just in case you want to have 2 ports & Unless its not a TCP (eg UDP)

If you are in Cent OS 32 bit, ensure that your kernel to use up more ports that it should.

This is to prevent port starvation & would quickly cripple your server.

Do the math, if you need to support 100 users, 100 x 2 = 200 open ports.

but in most cases, its only (65534 - 1024) ports available, so, if you could afford it, then its cool.

Also remember that most ISP's would block certain ports, so keep the right ports open for read / write.

regards

Comment: what do you mean with "that most ISP's would block certain ports" ?

Comment: Some ISP's would block certain ports, for eg, file sharing ports or typical gaming ports.

Comment: I remember in Essen, Germany, they blocked everything but FTP, HTTP & HTTPS

Comment: All your ports are belong to us?

Answer (score 2):

There's no significant performance advantage, and it can require much more code to handle two sockets than one, particularly on the server side.

You'd also still have to open both sockets from the client side, as most systems wouldn't permit the server to open a connection back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, TCP is optimised assuming you will send a request and get a response on the same socket, however the difference is likely to be trivial.

Often the simplest solution is also the fastest.

What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8735731/378737 this is my main problem. I am trying to figure out if I have configured netty correctly.

Comment: Certainly the behaviour you get is odd.  If you can, I would test a simple echo service which send packets small packets back and forth, if you can get something who has seen problems to help.  A typical ping time around the world should be less than 300 ms.  The problem you appear to have is testing what you have. Once you can do that, a solution should become more obvious.

Comment: Peter, thanks for the answer first of all. I have put my configuration in the following question do you have any suggestion ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8655973/378737

Comment: The main suggest is you have to be able to test what ever you do because I often come across things which should improve performance but don't and other things which shouldn't make much difference but do.